# SQL Server 2008 R2 sys.dm_exec_sql_text question

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, execution-plan

If i run the following query on our production server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT TOP 10
t.TEXT QueryName,
s.execution_count AS ExecutionCount,
s.max_elapsed_time / 100000 AS MaxElapsedTime,
ISNULL(s.total_elapsed_time / s.execution_count, 0) / 100000 AS AvgElapsedTime,
s.creation_time AS LogCreatedOn,
ISNULL(s.execution_count / DATEDIFF(s, s.creation_time, GETDATE()), 0) AS FrequencyPerSec
,s.plan_handle, s.plan_generation_num
FROM sys.dm_exec_query_stats s
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text( s.sql_handle ) t
ORDER BY
s.max_elapsed_time / 100000 DESC
```

My top queries are "create procedure ......." does this mean the sql server recompiles this stored procedure more then once?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, regarding your query that means, that this procedure takes much time than others

**And**

Periodically sql server recompiles procedures or its inner statements, it is an intended behavior depending from server activity, memory pressure, user commands, RECOMPILE option, amount of underlying data changes and many more.

**Update:**

The queries is started from CREATE PROCEDURE because sql server presents the SP's body in such a way.

You may even drill down into procedure's inner statements by this query:

```
Select 
    s3.name as [Obj Name], 
    s3.type as [Obj Type], 
    (select top 1 substring(text,(s1.statement_start_offset+2)/2,
    (CASE when s1.statement_end_offset = -1 then len(convert(nvarchar(max),text))*2
    else s1.statement_end_offset end - s1.statement_start_offset) /2 ) FROM sys.dm_exec_sql_text(s1.sql_handle)) as [SQL Statement], 
    execution_count, 
    plan_generation_num, 
    last_execution_time, 
    ((total_worker_time+0.0)/execution_count)/1000 as [avg_worker_time], 
    total_worker_time/1000.0 total_worker_time, 
    last_worker_time/1000.0 last_worker_time, 
    min_worker_time/1000.0 min_worker_time, 
    max_worker_time/1000.0 max_worker_time, 
    ((total_logical_reads+0.0)/execution_count) as [avg_logical_reads], 
    total_logical_reads+0.0 total_logical_reads,
    last_logical_reads+0.0 last_logical_reads, 
    min_logical_reads+0.0 min_logical_reads, 
    max_logical_reads+0.0 max_logical_reads, 
    ((total_logical_writes+0.0)/execution_count) as [avg_logical_writes], 
    total_logical_writes+0.0 total_logical_writes, 
    last_logical_writes+0.0 last_logical_writes, 
    min_logical_writes+0.0 min_logical_writes, 
    max_logical_writes+0.0 max_logical_writes, 
    ((total_logical_writes+0.0)/execution_count + (total_logical_reads+0.0)/execution_count) as [avg_logical_IO], 
    total_logical_writes + total_logical_reads+0.0 total_logical_IO, 
    last_logical_writes +last_logical_reads+0.0 last_logical_IO, 
    min_logical_writes +min_logical_reads+0.0 min_logical_IO, 
    max_logical_writes + max_logical_reads+0.0 max_logical_IO
from sys.dm_exec_query_stats s1
cross apply sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) as s2
join sys.objects s3 on ( s2.objectid = s3.object_id )
left join sys.schemas sch on(s3.schema_id = sch.schema_id)
where s2.dbid = db_id()
order by s3.name, s1.sql_handle
```

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, but why is the t.TEXT QueryName "create procedure ..." and not "exec ..."? thats gives me the headache..

Comment: See updated answer. And addition - sql server keeps the compiled query text - say me, what it should compile in EXEC someproc? 8-)

Comment: Im not sure what this query does but i get no results from it, i can only run it in my master database else i get a "Incorrect syntax" even if i remove the "where s2.dbid = db_id()" i still get no results, but any way thanks you answered my question!

Comment: The code definitely works - I use it every almost day

Comment: @Petoj If you can only run it in the `master` database then maybe the compatibility level of your user databases is lower. The `join` on `sys.objects` will end up excluding queries that belong to other databases.

Comment: Thats true the Compatibility level is set to 80.